# Jenkins Git Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, git, jenkins

I am trying to install a completely working Jenkins on my old PC with Ubuntu Server 12.04. I think my installation of Ubuntu Server and Jenkins was succesfull. I can access the Jenkins page by internet from any computer. So now I want Jenkins to access my private gitrepo on BitBucket.com. I have found this tutorial: [Configuring Jenkins Git Tutorial](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/configuring-jenkins-continuous-integration-server-to-work-with-git/) and I am stuck with step 3.5. With says do this:

```
cd /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace
git config user.email "some@email.com"
git config user.name "jenkins"
```

But with the first command I get the error:

```
-su cd: /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace: No such file or directory
```

Do I have to make this folder? But when I do:

```
mkdir /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace
mkdir: cannot create directory '/srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace': No such file or directory
```

I don't know much about all these things, because I am fairly new to this. I have come this far just because of all the tutorial on the internet, but now I am stuck :(

**Edit:**
I have tried the commando:

```
mkdir -p /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace
mkdir: cannot create directory: '/srv/jenkins': Permission denied
```

So I guess this is not the solution, because user `jenkins` doesn't have `sudo` rights. I hope some has another suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have it all working. The tutorial gave me a good start, but I never completed step 3.5. I did searching in all the options and there I was able to set all necessary options. And I went on with step 4 of the tutorial and filled all required fields.

Answer (score 1):

To create a whole path/set of directories, like you did with `/srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace` you need to pass the -p parameter to `mkdir` to create all of them at once.

```
mkdir -p /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but do you know if that is the intention of the tutorial? I think I should already have that folder. I have tried your command, but It didn't work out see edit.

Comment: You need to have super user rights, either log in a s `root` or use `sudo`, otherwise you will not have write access to `/` to create `srv`. On Ubuntu one typically does not have the password for `root`, but at least the first user created at installation is set as sudoer, i.e. can elevate his rights to super user by prefixing a command with `sudo`. Just call `sudo mkdir -p /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace`. Also see `man sudo` for more information on `sudo`.

Comment: The tutorial said do `sudo su - jenkins`, so that's why I find it strange to logout or use `sudo` rights. The `srv` folder already exists but the `jenkins` folder isn't.

Comment: As pointed out below by @ayr-ton, you need to create `jenkins` directory first and `chown` it to the `jenkins` user. The `sudo su - jenkins` from the tutorial makes you the `jenkins` user, so that all further operations are done using this user id. Do this first and then create the remaining directories `jobs/project/workspace` as needed to follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

With a user with sudo privileges, try:

```
sudo chown jenkins:jenkins /srv/jenkins
chmod 750 /srv/jenkins
```

Please, check first it the directory /srv/jenkins exists.

And then, try the `mkdir -p /srv/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace`.

Comment: The `jenkins` folder doesn't exist and I think it should already exist.

Comment: @martijnn2008 Try to create this with `sudo mkdir /srv/jenkins` before the `chown` command.